# Unable to access/use my Drupal site after .htaccess mistake

Tags: drupal

hoping i could get some quick help on this problem.

Here is the URL for my site: www.eastwestcards.com - I accidentally used the .htaccess file generated by drupal for someother sites on my hosting and I think this is what caused this error. Could anyone tell me how to fix this? It literally happened right after i copied the drupal .htaccess file and used it on another domain that uses drupal as well. This same error occurs when i try accessing my other domain which uses drupal.

This is the error that I am reading when i try to access my site 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /nfs/c07/h04/mnt/108263/domains/eastwestcards.com/html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 287

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: AddHandler php-stable .php - i added this to my current .htaccess file and it's working again. However, i never had that last time but drupal still worked. Any idea what's going on here? - also my other drupal site is still not working.

Comment: Always make a backup or use version control before changing .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you could find a answer http://drupal.org/node/1373932